# How does the shell theorem play into two objects just outside of a planet's boundaries gravity towards each other?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, symmetry

So the scenario I envision to represent this would be two meteors on opposites sides of a planet heading directly towards the planet. How would the shell theorem play into the two meteors gravitational pulls towards each other?

Comment: The shell theorem assumes spherical symmetry. This scenario is not spherically symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Newtonian gravity is additive, so the planet has nothing to do with the gravitational forces that the two meteors exert *on each other*.

If the planet has a spherically-symmetric mass distribution, then *its* gravitational pull on each meteor is the same as if its mass were concentrated in a point at its center.